# Angular 5 input not passing nested object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm puzzled about the behavior of Angular when using `Inputs` in child components to pass data through. I have an interface `IInterface` with the following structure:

```
export interface IInterface {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
    property3: IAnotherInterface;
}
```

I read that from an API and all works fine. However, inside that component I pass `IInterface` to child component:

```
<child-component [interface]="interface"></child-component>
```

All properties are passed correctly however the `IAnotherInterface` is null. Why is that? I changed it to be a class in case it needs somehow any kind of instantiation or anything like that but the end result is the same. I have that exact same problem and I get null for `property3` inside the `child-component`.

**UPDATE:**
This is the child component:

```
export class ChildComponent{
    @Input() interface: IInterface;
}
```

I have the Chrome debugger with a breakpoint at the parent's callback when getting the `IInterface` element and it's got all the information in there. Like I say `property1` and `property2` are both with data whereas `property3` remains null when I send the object down to the children.

Comment: Are you sure `property3` is initialised before you pass it to the child component? I've never had problems with missing values before. Could you also show the `child-component` definition?

Comment: Added the definition. I think all info is there basically because I use it in the parent component as well and it shows up

Comment: Actually interface is not a data. you shouldn't pass it as a param. Just export it and then import in Child component

Comment: @Alexander Poshtaruk The input variable is named `interface` and accepts an object of type `IInterface`. This is perfectly valid. I actually use the same approach in differenct places (with classes, but using typescript they're gone either way at runtime) and all complex data gets passed correctly. Have you tried converting `IAnotherInterface` to a class? It *shouldn't* make a difference, but with Angular you never know...

Comment: Found it, there was an extra call being made during this process and wasn’t returning the IAnotherInterface object back. Thanks @Cecilya !